# More than one credit card per account

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

I'm implementing an ATM simulator using databases.
The bank accounts that i'm holding have ( or not ) to be associated with more than only one credit card, each.
I know how to associate it with only one credit card each, by storing the credit card id in a field, but i don't know how to make it work if more than one credit card have access to a specific bank account.

What should i be looking for ?

BTW, i'm doing it in SQLite.

Comment: Sound like homework...  Have you heard the word _relational_, or _related table_ during the course ?

Comment: Is not a homework, but not for me, for me is an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Number of bank account in each credit card.

You must have bank account in credit card structure, not credit card structure in bank account structure, because **credit card is linked to account not account to credit card**!

Comment: And separate tables for accounts an credit cards. And I always thought that *primary keys* are one of the first things learned about relational DBs..

Comment: @ruslik: yes primary keys, ok;-) i dont write this because this is a little off-topic in this form of question.

Comment: It wasn't for you, but for OP :)